How to change a twilio parameter via a web site without logging into console
I have twilio flow that when triggered sends a message to a users cell number.  My problem is the cell number can change regularly and this has to be done manually through the twillio console.  I would like to build a small web app that can query and show the current active cell number and if that is not the number available to take requests then allow the user to change the cell number.  I think this can be done via the restAPI function, but I am a newb and I am not sure how to do this.  Anyone have any suggestions please ?
